# sublime text syntax definition hexadecimal char

Tags: sublimetext2

I have code with hexadecimal chars. I write own syntax definition

```
- match: \x0C\x0C\w+   
  name: variable.parameter.cstek
```

but after building its not highlited. Regexp pattern is working in regexp search ctrl+f

Comment: Can you add more information about your process? What are you "building" with, for example? What files are you dealing with?

Comment: @ProtractorNinja it looks like he's writing the regex in YAML and building to plist `.tmLanguage` format using [`AAAPackageDev`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AAAPackageDev). I use it for my own syntax development work.

Comment: @MattDMo yes, you are right. This is YAML syntax definition file